# Design pattern with delegate being used by multiple class

Tags: objective-c, swift, design-patterns, delegates, protocols

I want to send data from a class to other classes via delegation method. However i found a problem at which for each class which needs to listen to the data changes, i would have to create a separate delegate protocol for them.

```
protocol MainDelegateForA {
  func mainResultObtained(result: String)
}

protocol MainDelegateForB {
  func mainResultObtained(result: String)
}

class MainViewController: UIViewController {

  var delegateForA: MainDelegateForA?
  var delegateForB: MainDelegateForB?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    let subscribingViewA = SubscribingViewA()
    delegateForA = subscribingViewA
    let subscribingViewB = SubscribingViewB()
    delegateForB = subscribingViewB
    distributeResult("Calculation obtained!!!")
  }

  func distributeResult(result: String) {
    delegateForA?.mainResultObtained(result)
    delegateForB?.mainResultObtained(result)
  }

}

class SubscribingViewA: MainDelegateForA {

  func mainResultObtained(result: String) {
    print("SubscribingViewA got result:\(result)")
  }

}

class SubscribingViewB: MainDelegateForB {

  func mainResultObtained(result: String) {
    print("SubscribingViewA got result:\(result)")
  }

}
```

The above code is a over simplified version of what i meant.

Of course by

> keeping a reference of each class and send the result via directly calling a public method of the class

or

> Using notification and make every class that needs the changes to listen to the data change

is possible to be one of the solution but

> i want to write this very particularly using the delegation method

If it is possible, is there anyway i can achieve this without a separate protocol for each class?

Comment: Why don't you just use an array of delegates like `var delegates = [MainDelegateForA]()`?

Comment: I second that, an array should help you achieve what you're looking for

Comment: @luk2302, this seems to be a good way of doing it but what i left out in my question (sorry - over simplified) SubscribingViewA and SubscribingViewB are actually UITableViewCell and they will be created in cellForRowAtIndexPath. If i were to kept it as an array, the array will be huge when user keeps scrolling

Comment: that is a good point, maybe a `Set` would be a better alternative. *Or* you manage to unsubscribe the cells.

Comment: Bear in mind that typically you want to make references to delegates `weak` to avoid reference cycles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by luk2302, you can use an array of delegates to achieve it:

```
var delegates = [MainDelegate]()
```

Then you just need to use a loop (maybe it can be simplified in swift):

```
for delegate in self.delegates {
    delegate.mainResultObtained(result)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few patterns you can use.

1) You can allow multiple listeners, and have them register in much the same way target-action works.  Your class would iterate over the array of listeners and invoke the appropriate method.

2) You can use notifications instead.

I would lean towards the first approach, as that provides much more programming safety.